# PHP File Upload Does Nothing

Tags: php, forms, file, upload

I've had several upload forms working before, however, even after almost copying my previous code this on doesn't seem to work, I prefer doing it all in one php script file and so it is all generated in this single file.

My form:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="file">File : </label>
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file" required="required" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

My php upload:

```
if(!empty($_POST['file']))
{
    echo "Found.";
    $exts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $ext = end($temp);
    if((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
    && in_array($ext, $exts))
    {
        if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            $result = "Error Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            $scandir = scandir("/images/news/");
            $newname = (count($scandir-2)) . $ext;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"/images/news/" . $newname);
            $ulink = "/images/news/" . $newname;
            $result = "Success, please copy your link below";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $result = "Error.";
    }
}
```

When I upload a .png image, the page simply seems to refresh, I've placed the `echo "Found.";` in there to check if it even has anything in `$_POST["file"]` but it doesn't seem to have anything.

I don't understand why the page isn't submitting correctly. I've changed `action=""` to `action="upload.php"` to make sure it points to the same page but still nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$_FILES['file']` instead of `$_POST['file']`.

Read more about $_FILES at http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: I can't believe it was so simple! Thank you I should have picked up on this.

Comment: Happens to the best of us. Just mark this question as answered now.

Comment: I will do in 9 minutes, when the site lets me.

Answer (score 1):

replace `$_POST['file']` by `$_FILES['file']` and set `action=""`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.... because $_POST not work with files, for files we use $_FILES..

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file']))
{
    echo "Found.";
    $exts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $ext = end($temp);
    if((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
    && in_array($ext, $exts))
    {
        if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            $result = "Error Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            $scandir = scandir("/images/news/");
            $newname = (count($scandir-2)) . $ext;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"/images/news/" . $newname);
            $ulink = "/images/news/" . $newname;
            $result = "Success, please copy your link below";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $result = "Error.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't just check the $_FILES variable. I would name the submit input and check if the submit input was submitted. This way you can check if the button was pressed with no files selected and prompt the user as such.

Like So:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="file">File : </label>
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file" required="required" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Then you can check the post variable for that value.

Like So:

```
if(!empty($_POST['upload']))
{
    echo "Found.";
    $exts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $ext = end($temp);
    if((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
        && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
        && in_array($ext, $exts))
    {
        if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            $result = "Error Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            $scandir = scandir("/images/news/");
            $newname = (count($scandir-2)) . $ext;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"/images/news/" . $newname);
            $ulink = "/images/news/" . $newname;
            $result = "Success, please copy your link below";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $result = "Error.";
    }
}
```